# When creating category, it creates automatically tag, or, when creating tag, it creates automatically category in same name

Tags: categories, tags

I have a weird problem. For example, when i create `test` category, worpdress is creating tag as `test` automatically. Or vice versa. I tried everything i know.

1) Disabled theme and plugins.
2) Reinstalled wordpress.

Using wordpress latest version.

How can this be possible. Can i try another thing? Or you guys can you any advice me?

Comment: Are you seeing these dups in the admin or on the frontend?  Post a screenshot.

Comment: Seeing in wp-admin.

Comment: I know you said you tried but this has to be from a plugin or theme...

Comment: Yes i know but i tried deactivating all plugins and themes. Used twentynineteen.

Comment: So your saying at this point you have a completely fresh install of WP and this is still happening?  If that's the case I would make a bug report but I have doubts.

Comment: It not exactly fresh. I just tried with deactivating. Maybe it related database? If it is but, it must be valid all wordpress sites.

Comment: Deactivating plugins or themes most likely won't remove the categories and tags that were already added. You really would need to set up a fresh install of WP and then if the issue still occurs you can file a bugfix. But not having seen this on any other installs it's very unlikely it would be a bug, as many other people would have seen it already.

Comment: You should try installing a fresh WordPress site to confirm if it is related to your site or not.  If it doesn't happen on the fresh install, deactivate ALL plugins and ALL themes except default one, and then test .. activating plugins one by one until you find the one causing it